# What comes with Nintendo's DS SDK?

Tags: nintendo

Presumably a development machine for sure, but would it contain any sort of editor (of any kind)? Or are there any editors in existence that work with the SDK that are commercially available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The details of the content of the SDK are probably covered by NDA.

That said, since SDKs generally contain compilers and other related tools and libraries. Access to the development hardware is often a separate issue, although to most developers they will appear to be part of the same package.

You can use any text editor to write code, and just about any IDE that can work with external compilers (which is any decent one) can be made to incorporate the tools from a console SDK.

Comment: I suppose I meant: does the SDK some kind of standard level editor? Additionally are there any level editors that work with the Nintendo DS SDK?

Comment: I've seen a free SDK, and it does not

Comment: @Storm: The SDK is not an engine, so it wouldn't (and couldn't) have a level editor

Comment: @Blue Raja: That was pretty much my guess. The last question being: if it is not an engine, then the gameloop is left out and not provided for you?

Comment: Indeed; nor would there be level editors written "to the SDK" but rather editors written to engine technology (as in Unreal, et cetera) that happened to be portable to the platform.

Comment: @Storm Correct. You get very low-level tools -- far more akin to what you'd get downloading Visual Studio or GCC than you would downloading Unreal's engine.

Comment: @Josh Petrie: Are there any known engines (e.g. UDK) that deploy to the DS?

Comment: There is middleware for the DS (you can Google for them, "DS middleware" and such). Not very much though, and none of the really popular engines suites that you've probably heard of.

Answer (score 4):

It comes with compilers (Metroworks Codewarrior, and GCC via cygwin), lots of documentation, lots of sample code for different techniques, a Nintendo designed emulator, and optionally development hardware.  From a code perspective, it's all really low level, basically directly talking to hardware registers with macros.  Lower level than even something like OpenGL or Direct3D.

Comment: So they do not provide any default rendering mechanism that you can access from C?

Comment: "default rendering mechanism that you can access from C" ?? The nintendo DS does rendering in hardware based on the content of VRAM (including memory-mapped control registers e.g. for scrolling) and openGL-like commands issued to the 3D rendering pipeline. What else are you looking for ?